# PHP shared function in all Class functions

Tags: php

I have a class that has 20+ different API function call.  Each one is basically similar but there is one funciton I'd like shared between all of the.

For example:

```
public function first_api_call () {
$response = $client->get($uri, [
    'on_stats'  => function (TransferStats $stats) use ($logger) {
        // do something inside the callable.
        $logger->debug('Request' . $stats->getRequest() . 
                       'Response' . $stat->getResponse() .
                       'Tx Time' . $stat->getTransferTime()
        );
    },
]);
}
```

Now, I'd like for this tehnically to be `on_stats => run_my_stats_function` and have the code in that one place so it will take affect whereever it is called.

How do I go about doing this in a class?

Comment: If `on_stats` should be callable it can be something like `array(__CLASS__, 'method')`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `traits` which is a fancy name for "compiler assisted copy/paste", which is exactly what you're looking for :)

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php